# Can you build a database-application for Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Let's say I want to build a simple register:

There are `Person`s `Information`s and `Relationship`s.

Each `Person` has a `name` and a variable amount of `Information` attached to it.

Each `Information` has a `label` and a `description`.

Each `Relationship` has two `Person`s and a `description`.

As for views, when I click on a `Person`, it should give me all the information I have about that `Person` and provide links to all other people this `Person` is in one way or another connected to.

(probably) simplest design: relational database backend

So the way it's in my head, right now, a user would log in to the app with his google account. The app then creates the database(s) it needs in the user's drive and allows the user to add and delete `Person`s and `Information`s as well as connect two `Person`s with a description of their `Relationship`.

I'm kind of surprised Google still hasn't added a database application to its rooster.

And since basically everything I found that uses Google Drive as a "database" makes use of its Spreadsheets, I kind of wonder whether it's even supported or if I'm not better off thinking about a file-based approach.

So ***can*** you add a database to Google Drive at all? And if you can, where would I find more information about the *how*?

Comment: You want to create the database to your Google Drive, and you want to make users use the database by login to user's Google account. If my understanding is correct, how about using Web Apps? When Web Apps is deployed as "Execute the app as: Me" and "Who has access to the app: Anyone", I think that such situation can be achieve. You can see the detail information at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike not quite. I want *every* user to have his **own** database in his own Google Drive that is inaccessible to any other  user (including myself). The app would then access and modify that database only.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize I misunderstand your question. You want to make users use user's database on user's Google Drive. This situation can be achieved by deploying Web Apps as "Execute the app as: User accessing the web app" and "Who has access to the app: Anyone". I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Google spreadsheets work well for this use case. Also Google has several pure database products. Their names keep changing, but the most common is the one embedded in AppEngine. Creating a true database on top of Google Drive is problematic because of write consistency and concurrency.